# Registering XmlAdapter globally for any classes in different packages

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I'm using CXF 2.4 with JAXB.

Could I have a global XmlAdapter for all instances of my owm class (e.g. LWDate)?

I wrote a class:

```
public class LWDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Date, LWDate>
```

Right now I have to add `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on each param, method or package that I plan to use with CXF. E.g.

```
@WebMethod void test (@WebParam(name="Birthdate") @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LWDateAdapter.class) LWDate pBirthdate){}
```

I wish to ask CXF/JAXB always bind my class LWDate to java.util.Date is it possible?

**UPDATE:** `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` works on a package level staring from version 2.4.4 [according to that issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3205).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your use case using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation at the package level is your best option.   Below is a post where I use this strategy for the [**Joda-Time**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) classes:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

If you have a domain class that you always want to be handled with an `XmlAdapter` you can use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation at the type level:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Comment: I saw the post before my question. Unfortunately type level annotation doesn't work for me (no idea why, neither interface nor implementation). Package level is a bit weired approach IMHO. Jaxb 2.1 (built in Sun JDK).

Comment: According to the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3205 package level annotations doesn't work with CXF now (would be fixed in next version 2.4.4)

Comment: @FoxyBOA - If you use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) as your JAXB provider you could use our XML representation of the JAXB metadata:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html